# Dubai Airport : do I have to collect and recheck my luggage between airlines?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, uk-citizens, dxb

From Birmingham (UK) to Dubai terminal 3
From Dubai to Ahwaz (Iran) terminal 2

Comment: I understand your booking is on separate tickets ?

Comment: I don't think it's separate tickets, I'm not sure to be honest!!!

Comment: You made one reservation but you're flying with two airlines, is that right ?

Comment: I get my tickets on line from UK  to Iran with 6hrs transit and change the terminal also  from T3 to T2

Comment: That's right, from UK to Dubai with Emirate Airlines, to terminal 3 then from Dubai terminal 2 to Iran. Thank you  with fly Dubai airline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, you won't need to recheck your bags at DXB.

According to their [website](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/connecting_with_flydubai/connecting_with_flydubai.aspx), they'll do that for you

> Passengers travelling from Emirates destinations will have their baggage checked through to their final destination. They will also receive their boarding pass for the flydubai sector.